# How to create a cross project source release with Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project I need to release the source for. The problem I have is that I need to create a source release for all code that we have developed. The code is across multiple projects, but I want to leverage maven so that only the source for the jars we are actually using is released.

For example:

- core code project (multi module maven project)
- web app project (multi module maven project). Contains we app module plus some supporting jar modules. Depends on some jars from core code project.

Now I want to release all the source for the web app project but only the source for the core code project that the web app uses.

Can I do this with maven?

I have a feeling it is possible with assembly plugin and source plugin but it is not clear to me how to put this together.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is bit unclear. let me assume certain things and proceed.
I believe that following is your folder structure.

- web app project

  - some source code folder
  - pom.xml
- core code project

  - some source code folder
  - pom.xml

Take the core code project and change the version from previous version in pom.xml.
let 's say if it was 1.0 change it to 1.1

```
 <groupId>core code project related</groupId>
  <artifactId>core code project</artifactId>
  <name>core code</name>
  <version>1.1</version>
```

Make your changes to accomodate the web app project in core code project.

later,
in web app project add dependency for core code project in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>core code project related</groupId>
     <artifactId>core code project</artifactId>
     <name>core code</name>
     <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

In this way, 1.1 version of core project will have only web app related code.
Currently we are using this method. Hope it helps. let me know if you want something else.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a feeling it is possible with assembly plugin and source plugin but it is not clear to me how to put this together.

If I understood the question correctly, one solution would be to create an "aggregator" project listing all wanted modules (the relevant modules from the webapp and the relevant modules from the core) and to use the [`source:aggregate`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html) goal from the [Maven Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/).

Comment: This is very close to what I want, but I actually found out today that I need to include pom files and distribute in a form that can be built with maven. The solution I have come up with is to use the apache source-release assembly on the web app project. This is fine because I need all these sources. 

For the core project I created a customised version of the source-release assembly which explicitly selects the modules I need. Not very nice. But in the end I have two zip files with the source essential for building the project that we can give to someone else.

Comment: @zorro2b: Requirements from the future are hard to anticipate :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you want to do this, the pom from your web app project will explicitly list the versions of your code dependencies used, so you can find the source easily.   It sounds like you want to store the same artifact twice.  So if your web app uses `core-x-1.2.3.jar` and `core-y-4.5.6.jar` you would produce a web app sources artifact containing the source from both those core jars in addition to the actual web app source?

You can use the [maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to update your web app pom to use the latest versions of your core dependencies, I've automated that by running a shell script in a CI server in the past.  That means whenever you release a new version of your web app you will be using the latest release of your core code, and all you need to do is update your web app pom from version control.